# Are there any JBoss 5.1 Community Edition SecurityManager .policy file examples available?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, securitymanager

Googling "jboss security manager" brings up http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/security-manager-howto.html, but this is way out of date.